# How to reroute a payload from a 3rd party POST to a client via GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my Express app I am receiving a payload from an external POST request:

```
router.post('/liveReleaseStore', (req,res) => {
    let thing = req.body.myPayload
    ...
```

I also handle a GET request from my client:

```
router.get('/liveReleaseStore', (req, res) => {
  let myResponse = ...

  res.send(myResponse);
});
```

I need to reroute the payload so that when my client sends a GET to the server I am able to send back the data or tell the client that I haven't received any data yet.

What is the best way to about about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize the data outside the two functions to null. And then send the data if it's been initialized by the post function.

```
let thing = null;
router.post('/liveReleaseStore', (req,res) => {
  let thing = req.body.myPayload
  ...
}

router.get('/liveReleaseStore', (req,res) => {
  if (thing === null)
    return res.send('no data yet');
  res.send(thing);
}
```

Comment: I hadn't even tried this because I thought it would be out of scope, I should read more. Thanks!